# Are Apple mov files compatible with HLS media files?

Tags: http-live-streaming

I record a series of small (10 sec) mov files from an iDevice.  Are these files compatible with HLS media file format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HLS media format is MPEG2 TS, which is different from the MOV file that you create from the recording.

It's easy to convert an MOV to M2TS with a tool like ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.ts
```